# Non-secure websockets on HTTPS page in LAN

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I have an application which is a websocket server. During its initial setup, I've noticed that Chrome 60 allows to establish non-secure websocket connection from HTTPS page to localhost websocket server. Firefox 55 doesn't allow that.

The web page is served by web server in LAN, if that matters.

According to [websocket candidate recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/), it should not be allowed. But if I follow the link to [latest editor's draft](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network), there is no such restriction.

So I'd like to ask, which behavior is standardized? Should connection from HTTPS page to ws://localhost/ be allowed?